# Using an ontology XML document to help parse RDF data

Tags: c#, parsing, xml-parsing, rdf, opencalais

I'm working with Open Calais and am trying to parse RDF/XML data that's being returned from the API. I can't make my own parser because the data for the same type is sometimes different depending on how much info there is-

```
<!--PersonCareer: person: Bill Gates; company: Microsoft; careertype: professional; status: past; -->
```

vs

```
<!--PersonCareer: person: Margaret Cushing; position: president and chief executive officer; company: Hewlett-Packard; careertype: professional; status: current; -->
```

What I want to be able to do is to parse this RDF data using the ontology document Open Calais provides - http://www.opencalais.com/files/owl.opencalais-4.3a.xml. I need help with actually how to parse this data using the ontology xml doc using c#. Any help would be appreciated! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to parse RDF in C#, you would be best to use an existing RDF library such as [dotNetRDF](http://www.dotnetrdf.org/).

Incidentally, your code samples are confusing because you've only pasted XML comments. No RDF parser that I know of will do anything other than ignore comments.

Comment: Haha I didn't realize they were comments until a couple hours ago. I just went with a JSON approach... but thanks anyway :)